# SQL QUERY in VBA

Tags: sql, vba

What's the problem with this? I want to list those items `where material number from mm = Child_Material_Number From bom and Parent_Material_Number = ' '`.

Here is my code:

```
rs.open("SELECT Material_Number,Material_Descr_HU FROM mm m" & _
                " WHERE " & _
                "Child_Material_Number FROM bom" & _
                " = Material_Number FROM mm) " & _
                "AND Parent_Material_Number = ''",
                cn, _
                ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, _
                ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic _
                )
```

Comment: Can you add some examples data and give schema details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, the clause FROM tells the server what tables or queries to look into in search of the data. The query you are looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT mm.Material_Number, mm.Material_Descr_HU
FROM mm INNER JOIN bom
   ON mm.Material_Number = bom.Child_Material_Number
WHERE bom.Parent_Material_Number = ''
```

Also, always have in mind the basic SQL statement structure, which is:

```
SELECT [fields]
FROM [tables or queries]
WHERE [condition]
ORDER BY [fields]
```

The problem in your query is that you are including the FROM clause after and within the WHERE clause.
Of course, you could do this -and more- if you are nesting queries, but then you'd need a second SELECT clause.

There are plenty of SQL tutorials out there, and they are worth a look if you are planning to work with data in the future.

Comment: Parent_Material_Number in bom anyway

Comment: And can u tell me pls, how can i show the bom table with mm.Parameters ?!
`SELECT mm.Material_Number, mm.Material_Descr_HU, "bom.*"
FROM mm INNER JOIN bom
   ON mm.Material_Number = bom.Child_Material_Number
WHERE bom.Parent_Material_Number = '' `

Comment: Hello, Gábor, sorry- I didn't answer your question because I've been offline for a while. What do you mean, with mm.Parameters?

Comment: Hello, your answer was correctly enough to me. Thanks a lot.